# Global Pointer in C?(Multi-Level Array)

Tags: c

I want to make a multi level array.

But, this code is not going well.

How can this code run?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *i;

int main() {
    int a[] = {0,1,2};
    int b[] = {1,2,3,4};

    // I want this
    i[0] = a;
    i[1] = b;

    // This works well
    int *c[2] = {a,b};


    printf("%d\n",c[1][4]);
}
```

Comment: A pointer must be pointing somewhere before you can dereference it. If it doesn't then you have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Also don't forget that arrays (like `a`) naturally decays to pointers to their first element. I.e. `a` is equal to `&a[0]`. If you make `i` point somewhere valid, then `i[0]` is a single `int` value, which is not the same as `&a[0]` (which is of type `int *`). Your compiler should have complained about that.

Comment: Furthermore, don't forget that array-indexes are zero-based. That means an array of four elements have indexes from `0` to `3` (inclusive). Using e.g. `c[1][4]` is out of bounds, as you try to access the *fifth* element of `b`.

Comment: Finally, don't use global variables. And please get a couple of beginners books to start over with the chapters on arrays and pointers.

Comment: Why are you not using simply `int c[3][4] = { { 11, 12, 13, 14 }, { 21, 22, 23, 24 }, { 31, 32, 33, 34 } };`?

Comment: You're assuming a pointer is an array.  `i` is a pointer, it is not an array.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Because I will use pthread so i need global variable

Comment: `int c[3][4]` at file scope declares a global variable. You do not need pointers.

Comment: Columns will contain indexes of threads, and rows are stored in a function of the threads corresponding to the index. Also, since the number of threads is not a fixed value, that method is considered unreasonable.

Comment: To have a pointer to pointers to `int`, you could declare it with `int **i`. To allocate memory for those pointers, you could use `i = malloc(NumberOfPointers * sizeof *i);`. Then, for each of those pointers, you must assign it a value, perhaps with `i[k] = malloc(SomeNumber * sizeof *i[k]);`.

Answer (score -2):

```
Int I*[2];
```

Should do the trick as a now has some memory for those pointers

Comment: Uhm, no it won't work very well. Perhaps you meant `int *i[2];`?